# Unable to use folders with Google Picker on web browser on mobile

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, google-picker

Within web browsers on mobile devices, I am able to display the Google Picker, and select files.

However, I am unable to navigate into folders.

On Android, when I touch a folder, it selects it.  However, when I touch it again, it does nothing.  If I double-touch it, it zooms the browser.  If I touch-hold, nothing happens.

On iOS, when I touch a folder, it also selects it.  However, touching it again, or double-touching, or touch-hold, nothing happens.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a coding problem or a device issue?

Comment: I believe it is a coding problem of the google picker itself.  We simply display the picker, and let it go, and it doesn't work.  I am hoping someone else has encountered it and found a workaround, or has seen it work successfully so I know it is something we have done.

Comment: If it's a coding problem, maybe you can post some codes you've implemented?